# Compilation to multiple files in Stylus

Tags: css, stylus

### 1. Briefly

I have 7 CSS files for pages design of my site. Designs differ only by colors. Everything else in the CSS files is duplicate information.

I have static site (HTML+CSS+JavaScript), I use Stylus.

Can I use any method reduce the amount of code not to write the same thing in my 7 CSS files?

---

### 2. Examples

For example, I have `SashaYellowDesign.css` file:

```css
.SashaFirstClass {
    color: yellow
}

.SashaSecondClass {
    background-color: black;
    border-color: green
}

// Many another classes
```

And `SashaRedDesign.css` file:

```css
.SashaFirstClass {
    color: red
}

.SashaSecondClass {
    background-color: white;
    border-color: blue
}

// Many another classes
```

As can see, the files differ only in colors.

---

### 3. Not helped

I don't find, how I can solve my problem in:

1. Google,
2. [**Stylus documentation**](http://stylus-lang.com/).

---

### 4. Do not offer

1. Yes, I can slightly reduce the code size, if I use `SashaYellowDesign.styl` and `SashaRedDesign.styl` files. But I still have to write duplicate information in each `styl` file. Please, do not offer this method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you try using variables and imports.

Below is how a theme is done with SCSS but I'm sure the same can be achieved with Stylus

In your case you'd have `_color-red.styl`, `_color-yellow.styl` and these files would only contain variables, no css descriptions.

`_color-red.styl`

```
@main-color: red;
@border-color: red;
...
```

And the other color

`_color-yellow.styl`

```
@main-color: yellow;
@border-color: yellow;
...
```

So your `core.styl` would only have:

```
body{
  color: @main-color;
  border-color: @border-color;
}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer! 

(Offtop) `_color-red.styl`, but not `color-red.styl` — it is a conventional or your personal filenames style?